Troubleshoot python function
I need to look through all apps in the graph API and return the app ID for the app where the app display name contains the "PROJECT NAME" that I am passing when I am calling the function. For example the app name in graph api is xyz - PROJECT NAME abc. I need my function to run through all apps and when it finds the "PROJECT NAME" in the display name, it should return the corresponding app ID. I tried using the contains function but looks like that is not supported in graph api. I dont what the filter query will be. How can I achieve this?
Here is the code snippet of the function:
def get_service_principal_app_id(project_name, bearer_token):
    # Construct a filter query that matches the pattern of the app name in Azure AD
    filter_query = Not sure
    url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter={filter_query}&$count=true"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": ******",
        "Content-Type": "*******",
        "ConsistencyLevel": "eventual"
    }
    
    # Pagination handling
    while url:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            service_principals = response.json().get('value', [])
            for sp in service_principals:
                display_name_parts = sp['displayName'].split(" - ")
                if len(display_name_parts) > 1 and display_name_parts[1].strip().lower() == project_name.strip().lower():
                    service_principal_id = sp['id']
                    application_id = sp['appId']
                    logger.info(f"Service Principal ID: {service_principal_id}")
                    logger.info(f"Application ID: {application_id}")
                    return service_principal_id, application_id
            url = response.json().get('@odata.nextLink', None)
        else:
            logger.error(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
            return None, None
    logger.error("Service Principal not found with the project name after the dash in display name")
    return None, None


Are you missing something after filter_query = ?

I just dont know what to put there. Thats why I kept it empty. I initially tried with contains function but graph API doesnt support that

Hi @Jimmy Could you confirm whether your requirement is to fetch app ID and SP ID of these apps containing PROJECT NAME in it? https://i.imgur.com/OjoTx9d.png

Instead of $filter, try to use $search. $filter doesn't support contains, but with $search query parameter, you should be able to find all service principals with displayName that contains the name of the project.
search_query ="\"displayName:Project Name\""
url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$search={search_query}&$count=true"
headers = {
    "Authorization": ******",
    "Content-Type": "*******",
    "ConsistencyLevel": "eventual"
}

